# IE not showing site content but still has source code

Tags: html, internet-explorer

[My website](http://kidmunication.com/) is loading fine in FireFox, but only loads the background image in IE despite the fact that all the source code is there.

I have validated the HTML with w3, so that shouldn't be the problem...

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the background is only loaded in IE but not in FireFox?

Comment: Look at the site - in IE only the background is visible

Comment: Please specify the IE version.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be falling over on your (enormous) `<style>` element. Probably something to do with your attempt to be valid XHTML that is HTML compatible while also stopping Netscape 1 (yes, version one) and friends from rendering the CSS as text.

Move your CSS and JS to external files.

Answer (score 0):

in IE 8+ hit F12 and u will see the processing stops at header somewhere...

DOM is not even loaded...